# When can I ,and how should I substitute limits in function with a sequence in proof writing?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, proof-writing

I've seen bunches of proofs choose a sequence to deal with problem of limits of function (for example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373293/showing-that-the-left-hand-limit-function-is-left-continuous)). But I can't quite understand when can I and how should I use a technique like this.

I've checked my calculus textbook and found a theorem says that: $lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=l$ iff for all sequence ${x_n}$ that converges to $x_0$,$lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=l$.

Does this means that I can do the translation from limits of function to limits of sequence if I can guarantee that for every sequence ${x_n}$ it holds that $lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$ converges? But I am really confused because there are always some specific sequences chosen in proofs, for example $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$. So why? And When can I ,and how should I substitute limits in function with a sequence in proof writing?

Any help would be appreciated!

Best regards.

Comment: What's an example where you choose a specific sequence such as $1/n$? As you say, to prove the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = l$ you need to show  $\lim_{x_n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = l$ for every sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$, not some particular sequence.

Comment: If you want to show the limit does *not* exist, though, you can find any particular sequence with $\lim_{x_n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) \neq l$ (or DNE).

Comment: @JairTaylor OH! I think I get it. So I come up with another question : why should we use sequence to solve problem in limits of function? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sometimes there are advantages of solving problems using sequences if there are theorems that are phrased in terms of sequences, such as "sequential compactness".  Also sometimes it's convenient to define things in terms of sequences, such as defining completeness in terms of Cauchy sequences, or limits of infinite sums. In general, it's just another tool in your toolbelt. Cheers